# how to select a span with in a particular class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row_class_name">
    <td><span></span></td>
    <td>...</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

now I want to hide the `<span>` element within the `<td>`. I am trying to use
`$('.row_class_name span')`, but it does not seem to work.

How would I do this correctly?

Comment: ..unless of course he's using a crappy browser that omits the whole <tr> tag because its improperly closed. then it wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('.row_class_name').find('span')
```

If just first column,

```
$('.row_class_name td:first').find('span')
```

Answer (score 6):

As Kevin says, your code should work. It is possible it is not working **because you are not closing the `<tr>` tag.**

Confirmed that the issue is your invalid HTML. Please see working example here. All I did was close the `<tr>` tag.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/24NVp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It works just [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/a2C87/). Although your markup needs some correction specifically the closing `</tr>` tag.